# If two different linear combinations of two random variables are Gaussian, can we deduct both of them are Gaussian.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If two different linear combinations of two random variables are Gaussian, can we deduct both of them are Gaussian. Mathematically, if we know that
$a_1X+b_1Y$ and $a_2X+b_2Y$ have Gaussian distributions and $a_1b_2 \neq a_2b_1$, can we prove that $X$ and $Y$ must be Gaussian?

Comment: I know the answer is yes when $a_1$ or $b_1$ is zero  (similarly when $a_2$ or $b_2$ is zero); so I'm looking for the answer when $a_1 b_1\neq0$ and $a_2 b_2\neq0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U$ be standard normal. Let $V=RU$, where $R$ is a Rademacher random variable that takes values $-1$ and $1$, each with probability $1/2$. Suppose $U$ and $R$ are independent. Let $X=\frac{U+V}{2}$ and $Y=\frac{U-V}{2}$.

Then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are each normal. But $X$ is not normal, for it takes on value $0$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Remark**: Suppose that $U=a_1X+b_1Y$ and $V=a_2X+B_2Y$ are *independent* normal, and  $a_1b_2-a_2b_1\ne 0$.  Then we  can almost  conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are normal. "Almost," because we have to declare constant random variables to be normal.  We can solve for $X$ and $Y$ in terms of $U$ and $V$, and use the fact that a linear combination of independent normals is normal. The condition of independence can be weakened, for example to $(U,V)$ being bivariate normal.

Comment: How do you prove $ X−Y=V=RU $ is normal?

Comment: One can do it by calculating the cdf.  The event $RU\le t $ can happen in two ways, $U\le t$ and $R=1$ or $U\ge -t$ and $R=-1$. But by symmetry $\Pr(U\ge -t)=\Pr(U\le t)$.

Comment: For future readers, this is actually the correct answer, not the one chosen.  See Andre's comments on the chosen answer.

Comment: Can anyone provide us with a reference where we can fine the formal proof for what is mentioned in the above "Remark"? I mean, how we can prove if $ (U,V)$ are jointly normal, then $(X,Y)$ will be normal too?.

Comment: I googled jointly normal sum random variables  and got a huge bunch of hits. [This one](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php) seems to do it. You may also want to look under bivariate normal.  It is also in "all" the textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Write this in matrix form, so you have $\mathbf {AX} = \mathbf Z$ where $\mathbf Z$ is bivariate normal. Then $\mathbf X = \mathbf {A^{-1}Z}$. The RHS is a linear combination of Gaussians, therefore the LHS is Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

To be a lot simpler than the other answers, just use the fact that the sum of two Gaussian random variables is gaussian and the fact that the scalar multiple of a Gaussian random variable is also Gaussian. The first of these facts can be worked out by computing the convolution of two arbitrary Gaussian distributions. The second requires some thinking about how things scale.

That is, $a_2(a_1X+b_1Y)$ and $-a_1(a_2X+b_2Y)$ must both be Gaussian and so must their sum $(a_2b_1-a_1b_2)Y$. Here we use the fact that $a_2b_1\neq a_1b_2$ to divide out the front term to conclude that $Y$ must be Gaussian.

Then by using a similar procedure as above, we can work out that $X$ must be Gaussian too, and then we are done.

Comment: The above proof assumes implicitly that a linear combination of normals is normal. That is true under suitable conditions, but not universally true.

Comment: What conditions are required? Linear independence? I realized I assumed that the random variables are linearly independent.

Comment: Independence of the two random variables you are taking the linear combination is certainly enough. One does not *need* that much, bivariate normal is enough, but one needs *something*.